# How can I remove the thin grey border on this SVG UK union flag?

Tags: svg

I'm trying to use this set of flags on my website:

https://lipis.github.io/flag-icon-css/

They're not perfect though, so I thought I'd help out and make some contributions to the project.

Since I live in the UK, this one stood out to me immediately:

https://lipis.github.io/flag-icon-css/flags/4x3/gb.svg

Here's the code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="flag-icon-css-gb" viewBox="0 0 640 480">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="a">
      <path fill-opacity=".7" d="M-85.3 0h682.6v512H-85.3z"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g clip-path="url(#a)" transform="translate(80) scale(.94)">
    <g stroke-width="1pt">
      <path fill="#006" d="M-256 0H768v512H-256z"/>
      <path fill="#fff" d="M-256 0v57.2L653.5 512H768v-57.2L-141.5 0H-256zM768 0v57.2L-141.5 512H-256v-57.2L653.5 0H768z"/>
      <path fill="#fff" d="M170.7 0v512h170.6V0H170.7zM-256 170.7v170.6H768V170.7H-256z"/>
      <path fill="#c00" d="M-256 204.8v102.4H768V204.8H-256zM204.8 0v512h102.4V0H204.8zM-256 512L85.3 341.3h76.4L-179.7 512H-256zm0-512L85.3 170.7H9L-256 38.2V0zm606.4 170.7L691.7 0H768L426.7 170.7h-76.3zM768 512L426.7 341.3H503l265 132.5V512z"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I understand why he's cropped it (to keep all flags the same aspect ratio).  I've fixed the colours already, but what I can't seem to do is shift that thin border that you can see around the edge of the image (specifically on the white parts).

Can anyone educate me/help?  Is it in fact just a rendering bug/artefact in Chrome?  Edge doesn't seem to show it, for example..?

Comment: Have you tried opening the file in a graphic application? That would make it easier to figure out how the image is constructed.

Comment: That SVG looks quite uggly to me. Using `path`s for rectangles, using a `clip-path` instead of just setting the coordinates correctly, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Problem

The *thin gray border* is not a *thin gray border*, it's the blue shape, a full rectangle, under the white shape. Editing the .svg in Codepen and hiding the blue part of the code, the thin border disappears

```
<!--<path fill="#006" d="M-256 0H768v512H-256z"/>-->
```

[image: Codepen]

### Solution

Now the SVG is a blue rectangle below and the white and red pieces on top. It should be a white rectangle below and the red and blue pieces on top.

[image: Flag]

Comment: The frustrating thing is if you remove the clipPath you get the full-width flag, with, you guessed it, still a thin border.  So given that the clip path clips both the white and the blue bit evenly, that means this has to be a rendering bug in Chrome, I think?

Comment: Answer updated with a solution

Comment: Impressively quick work, thank you!  What bit of software would you recommend I use for working on these flag files?  I've got Inkscape installed, but I don't know if there's much better options.

Comment: I think Inkscape is a valid option, I usually work with Illustrator. But I guess for this kind of jobs both are similar.

Comment: @Danielillo There's also Affinity Designer.

Comment: If you just swap the colours in the original blue for white, you still get the same issue of the anti-aliased rendering giving a border, which suggests strongly that simply swapping the order will not have the desired effect. The old Anti-Grain site had some good stuff on the difference between anti-aliasing and exact coverage - http://www.antigrain.com/svg/index.html